# Database manual counter increase issue

Tags: java, spring

I'm developing a REST API using Java and Spring Boot to manage purchases and customers. In my MySQL database, I have a table `Purchase` with a column that stores the unique `ticketId`. It is not the primary key.

When a new purchase is added (by doing a `PUT` request), I create a new purchase from data provided in the request, obtain the max `ticketId`, increment it by one, and store it in database. Primary key is auto-incremented.

This is my code:

```
@Transactional
public boolean saveNewPurchase(PurchaseDTO data) {
  Purchase p = createPurchaseFromData(data);
  Long idTicket = purchaseDao.getMaxIdTicket();
  p.setIdTicket(idTicket + 1);
  save(p);
}
```

Are there concurrency issues here? Let's say two `PUT` requests executes this method in parallel, could they retrieve the same max `idTicket` so violate unique `idTicket` constraint when save the second purchase?

If so, how could I solve it? Would making the method `synchronized` solve the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I think first consider, why are you doing that? If you want another transaction-safe incrementing identifier that's not the primary key, why not create another table called ticket_ids with an auto_increment primary key. Then insert into that to obtain your next ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a concurrency issue here. Two different threads could get the same `maxIdTicket`, and then save the Purchase with the same `ticketId`.

I see 3 solutions here :

- Use synchronized
- Use an `AtomicInteger` to keep the counter in memory
- Use a specific table in MySQL, with only one column, `AUTO_INCREMENT` and insert/get a row each time you need a counter value. With other RDBMS, you could use a sequence, but I am pretty sure there is no sequences in MySQL.

The first 2 solutions are not working in distributed environment, so I would do the third.

Comment: There is a fourth and that is to use proper transaction propagation and locking at the db level.

Comment: This has nothing to do with transaction propagation. I think you mean transaction isolation.

Comment: Can you guys explain me what transaction isolation consist of?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is certainly prone to concurrency issues. One suggestion is to keep counter in memory with AtomicInteger, so that you wouldn't end up getting current maxId always from DB which might cause race conditions. So, when application starts up, by querying the DB, it could store the maxId in memory. This is robust, even in case of any crash, it could always the read the information from DB.

This won't work in distributed environment, in that case, having another table dedicated for storing the counter, is the better approach, as suggested by JamieB, in comments.

Comment: Only in a single instance, single node approach. If you have multiple instances this approach still won't work...

Comment: Perhaps for multi node you could use a similar approach but store the value in something like Hazelcast?